# How can I make drawline set onClickListener?

Tags: java, android, drawable

I want to make a line clickable.

I made a code using onDraw, in canvas.

I tried but, drawline(line) is not a object, so onclicklistener couldn't connect to line.

so I made a 2x2 rectangles arraylist, like a line to connect to clicklienter.

But I think there must be a better solution.

I think path... but path.... how can I connect to clicklistener???

and.... line???

there is no line class.....make a line class? how? line by drawline contains only X1,Y1, X2,Y2.. but clickable line must have x1,y1 to x~ y~....

please help me...

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to override onTouchEvent for the view, and when a touch occurs determine if it was on the line or not.

Comment: The formula for distance to a line is at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line.  Really you don't need it to be ecactly on the line (a few pixels off should still count), so look for the distance being less than some threshold value